# Como posso pegar o token JWT depois de autenticar?

Tags: spring-boot, react, token, jwt

Tenho uma API Rest spring-boot que, quando um usuário autentica a api retorna o token jwt, observei no browser que o token aparece no Response Header > Authentication e nos testes com o Postman ele mostra na Body.

Como eu posso pegar esse token para armazenar na Local Storage do navegador pelo Reactjs ?

Meu código que faz as requisições esta assim:

```
import { ACCESS_TOKEN, API_BASE_URL } from '../constants';

export function request (options) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        headers.append('Authorzation', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN))

    }

    return fetch(API_BASE_URL+options.url, {
        method: options.method,
        headers: headers,
        body: options.body
    })
    .then(function(response){ 

        // Falta pegar o token e gravar na local estorage

        if(!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(json);
        }
        return json;

    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Para adicionar ao localStorage é só usar o setItem(CHAVE, VALOR). 
Não sei qual estrutura do seu response, mas seria mais ou menos assim:

```
localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.value.jwt);
```